# MySQL query for highest and lowest sales

Tags: mysql

I have a table sales as below:

Quantity Sold | Name

5             | Real

6             | Chocolate

7             | Soda

8             | Real

Now I want to know the highest sales product name. Here answer is Real(5+8=13) and also less sold product name which is Chocolate.

What will be the query for mysql?

Comment: SO isn't the place to ask for people to write code for you really. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What have you tried so far????  SO is not a free coding service.  Post your query.  If it's not correct, we can help you.  But if you can't even do this simple query, I suggest you find other profession.

Comment: NO idea thats why asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select sum(`Quantity Sold`) quantity, name
from table
group by name
order by sum(`Quantity Sold`)
limit 1;

select sum(`Quantity Sold`) quantity, name
from table
group by name
order by sum(`Quantity Sold`) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks alot man i forgot about using order by. Thanks a lot :D.